# algo complexity - constantly scanning for lowest element in loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

We have this code

```
public void min(List<List<Integer>> lists) {
    
    int count = lists.size();
    int[] ind = new int[count]; //keeps track of traversal progress of each list
    int done = 0;
    while(done != count) {

        done = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minListIndex = -1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {

            List<Integer> curList = lists.get(i);
            if(ind[i] >= curList.size()) {
                done++;
                continue;
            }
            
            int curElement = curList.get(ind[i]);
            if(curElement < min) {
                min = curElement;
                minListIndex = i;
            }
            
        }
        
        if(minListIndex > -1) ind[minListIndex]++;
        
    }
    
}
```

in a glance, time complexity of this method is O(n) where n is sum(curList.size()). however, since each element may be scanned n times (at worst), will this make the complexity O(n^2) instead of O(n)?

Comment: O(n) = infinity, as long as two list don't end during the same inner for loop, as you reset `count` everytime you start the while loop. I would suggest you fix the code, even explain what it does, because it has problems beyond complexity at this point (like the update of ind[i] seems off)

Comment: @AloisChristen `count` is never reset, only `done`

Comment: right, my bad. Then the complexity should be O(m*n), where m is the number of lists, and n the total number of elements.